# Why won't live sass compiler generate my css files?

Tags: css, sass

I've checked my settings and everything looks good. I'm able to generate the folders but no css files? Thanks for the help.

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    //"java.home": "C:/jdk-14.0.2.12-hotspot",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "savePath": "/dist/css"
        }
    ],
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Night Wolf (dark blue)",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
    
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [


        "**/node_modules/**",
        ".vscode/**"
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, check that you are using [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass) and not [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass), which is not maintained anymore.

Comment: @Arkellys Switched them. same issue?

Comment: Do you get any information in the output window? Any kind of error message?